# Convert saved xml file to excel sheet

Tags: excel, xml, vba

i have xml file saved on my local PC and i want to convert it to excel sheet using the VBA by using the **.getElementsByTagName** method

how can i achieve that ?

i was trying something like :

```vb
Sub Include_Xml()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
 
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\shlomoe\Downloads\TEST2.xml")

Set myNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")


    For Each myNode In xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")
      i = i + 1
      WS.Cells(i + 1, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text
      WS.Cells(i + 1, 2) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_NUMBER")(0).Text
    Next myNode
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What isn't working with your code? Any error messages? If so, what are they and where do they occur?

Comment: The error is "object variable or with block variable not set"
the error appears on line :
WS.Cells(i + 1, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text

Comment: You aren't setting WS to refer to a worksheet.

Comment: OK I change it  to
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Items")

Comment: Now i get "Method or data member not found" on line : 
WS.Cells(i + 1, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text

Comment: Looks OK now Thank you !

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Items")

Comment: The xml file contain 20000 lines and it takes 10 minutes till completion. is there any way to improve it ?

Comment: Looping throug cells by means of VBA can be time consuming: Assign data to a 2-dim array and eventually write it back to the wanted target by one codeline; there are numerous fine examples here at SO  @Shlomo :-)